# Fixing WindowBuilder UI

Tags: java, swing, windowbuilder

The bug is hard to explain so I will add images to show my problem. As you can see in the provided picture the interface is completely empty. Does anyone know how to fix this? I have reinstalled eclipse and the addon multiple times and tried plenty of online tutorials but to no success.

[image: empty components, properties and palette]

Also, the code that was used is the base JPanel code that is generated when selecting it from the "New -> Other -> JPanel"

Comment: Java is not the same as Javascript, please avoid tagging your questions with both tags.

Comment: Why should anything be there?

Comment: Well, following tutorials, once they set up WindowBuilder and start using it they get option to edit windows using this UI, for me nothing is shown here.

Comment: Make sure that the WindowBuilder plugin is installed, or go to the source view rather than the Design view. You can find information and a download link here: https://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/

Comment: WindowBuilder is installed, the only problem is that it wont show any options in the palette.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well here is a way to fix this:

- reinstall eclipse
- set JDK compliance to 11
- Add JRE System library 1.7
- Install WindowBuilder (You may be forced to use 1.9.4 or 1.9.5 for compability, download it from their website and use )
- This should get you set to go :D

In case your get any kind of errors use the marketplace to update your WindowBuilder and that should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on my manjaro linux where I recently installed eclipse IDE 2021-12. I'm using jdk 17 . I tried several solutions that I found on google without success.
In fact, I had installed from the eclipse marketplace version 1.9.7 of windowbuilder; and when I had to open a source file in the windowbuilder editor, the components palette was always empty.

I can list here what I tried to solve my problem:

1. I tried the tutorials that talked about installing the windowbuilder
   plug-in from **Help -> Eclipse Marketplace** or from **Help -> Install New
   Software ->** -> **add a zip file**, but in these types of tutorials,
   eclipse versions that are used, was released before 2019, and this solution didn't work on my 2021-12
   version.
2. I tried an upgrade to windowbuilder 1.9.8, but I still had the same problem

Here is a simple manipulation that worked for me:

=> I did an update (actually an upgrade) to 1.9.8 but before that I had to change a configuration in the preferences, consisting of automatically associating all java GUI files with the windowbuilder editor:

1. **Window -> Preferences -> Windowbuilder** and I checked the checkbox *"Associate Windowbuilder editor with automatically recognized Java GUI files"*.
2. I restarted eclipse so that the configuration takes effect in the
   workspace by doing : **File -> Switch Workspace** and I choose the same
   workspace I was in and this has the effect of restarting eclipse.
3. Once eclipse was restarted, I went to the eclipse Marketplace and updated
   my windowbuilder and after restarting, everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Eclipse 2022-03 and WindowBuilder 1.9.8. WindowBuilder was running, I could open files in the WindowBuilder Editor with Design and Binding tabs, but pressing the Design tab showed an empty palette.

I did an uninstall of WindowBuilder (from the Help-> Eclipse Marketplace, then search for windowbuilder) and then installed the 1.9.9 nightly build. Maybe the 1.9.8 would work as well but this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have before the same problem. I have now resolved it.
Just do these steps.

1. Goto Help- Eclipse Market Place
2. Search Window Builder - If u already installed, Click install or else do download.
3. Check that the installed tab, Window builder is updated or not. If not do Update.
4. After finishing the update and restart. Your Problem Resolved.